# create new web application in yii 2 advanced

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I just started to try yii php framework, i have followed all the installation tutorial and I can run the yii framework, but i got stuck when I wanted to create a new web application by using command prompt.
the following command is like
`cd c:\xampp\pathtoyii\framework`
then
`yiic webapp newWebAPP`

the problem is in my yii folder doesn't contain framework folder and yiic file that i must write in the following command. anyone know this issue?

here is my yii folder root

[image]

no framework folder there.

actually, I need a path like this

[image]

and this is the framework folder.
[image]

is there any different in new version of yii that I installed?

Comment: check this url http://www.freetuts.org/tutorial/view?id=5 also  read yii2 official site content care fully http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html hope it will helpful to you

Comment: i have done that following installation and there were no framework folder. @jilesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue here is you are mixing Yii1 and Yii2.  If the tutorial you are reading references "yiic", that is Yii1, not Yii2.  The framework folder you show also is from Yii1.

I'm not sure if you are trying to write a Yii1 or Yii2 app.  If Yii2, check out the instructions for setting up a new app here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html  If Yii1, here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.installation

They are very similar, but are fundamentally different frameworks as Yii2 is NOT backwards compatible.

Comment: well done! finally you come to fix the issue.. actually I was trying to write yii2 app.. but in many tutorial, i got the folowing command that I must create new webapp by using yiic and there were no explanation what version that the command used for..  okay, I don't need the framework folder then.. thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

[Read the installation guide!](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md)
First, you must [install a composer](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md#installing-via-composer-). 
Than, require asset plugin:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

and install project:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii-application
```

Comment: i've followed this installation, but there were no framework folder in my yii folder, it just have backend and frontend folder..

Answer (score 0):

**Yii2 Installation Following command:**

**(1) First install Composer (LINUX):**

Locally:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

OR

**(1) First install Composer (WINDOWS):**

```
C:\Users\username>cd C:\bin

C:\bin>php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

Note: If the above fails due to readfile, use the http url or enable php_openssl.dll in php.ini

```
C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat

C:\Users\username>composer -V
```

Composer version 27d8904

**(2) Yii2 framework online downloads:**

Basic App:

```
php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.0-beta
```

Advanced App:

```
php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.0-beta
```

**(3) Other App Settings Command:**

```
php init

php yii migrate
```

Comment: I think you miss understanding about my question, I've done the installation and i can run the yii framework, the problem is i want to create a new web application by using command like `yicc webapp newWebApp` , but in my yii folder that i install, there is no framework folder and no yiic file, so that, i couldn't run that following command. please check my question, I've updated image for the clearance.